# Limit of $\lim_{t \to \infty}e^{i \omega t}$

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

I have that: 
$$\lim_{t \to \infty}e^{i \omega t}= \lim_{t \to \infty}cos(\omega t)+i \,sin( \omega t)$$

Since this is an oscilating function I kwow that $\lim_{t \to \infty}e^{i \omega t} \neq \infty$

But how can I obtain the limit of this function?

Comment: What has $\;x\;$ to do with the function?

Comment: my mistake, it would be $\lim t \to \infty$, let me edit it

Comment: A periodic function cannot have a limit at infinity unless it's constant.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

e^(iwt) is the answer since it is contant with respect to x.

Comment: True, but surely it's not what the OP intended to ask.

Comment: I am sorry, the limt was $t \to \infty$, I edited the question

Comment: @IvanMartinez don't click the green check mark unless the post has answered your question.  Click the green checkmark again to "uncheck" this answer.